# Android - Paused music automatically restarts to play after answering a phone call

Tags: android, media-player, playback, phone-call

I have an application that sets a rtsp stream of a song. When I push the "play" button on the application, the music starts playing. Then, when I push the "pause" button, the music is paused.

However, while the music is paused, if I receive a phone call, answer it, and then finish the call, the paused music AUTOMATICALLY restarts to play!! I DON'T want that to happen (because the user left the music paused)! I want the music to remain paused.

How do I fix this? I guess it's an Android problem!

PS: Just as a note, the oppose situation works fine, that is, if I receive a call while a music is being played, the Android does the right thing: it pauses the music for me to answer the call and, after the call is finished, the music starts to play again from where it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app has an implementation of PhoneStateListener somewhere that pauses the music when a call begins and restarts it when the call ends. You need to save the current state of the music (paused or playing) when a call begins and when the call ends, only start playing the music if it was playing when the call started. It's difficult to be more specific without your code but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378260/phonestatelistener-doesnt-call) has an example implementation.

Comment: I would need an activity to do this, right? I can't rely on a activity. The user might push the "play" button, push the "pause" button and then leaves the activity (with the music paused in the service). So I can't rely in Activity's methods. Is there any other solution to this? It seems to be Android's MediaPlayer problem. It, for some reason, doesn't know when not to restart a music when the calls ends.

Comment: Services can also register listeners.

Comment: Hummm, that's probably the way to go. I'll try something here. THanks!

Comment: I implemented the onCallStateChanged method of the PhoneStateListener class and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Could probably use more info, but just adding your `pauseMusic()` function in the activity's `onPause()` event should do the trick

Comment: Hello connoisseur. Thanks fore replying. The song actually plays in a service. So the solution of onPause() won't work because the activity that shows the player controls doesn't need to be shown. Is there anything I can do in the service?